# self join with count unique in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 2 columns; student IDs and major. Some students have a double major (or more) hence have multiple entries. I want to find the most commonly declared double majors, rank them in descending order, based on the number of students, keeping only double majors that have at least 2 students.
example:

| StudentID | Major |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | Science |
| 100 | Maths |
| 200 | Engineer |
| 200 | Maths |
| 201 | Arts |
| 300 | Biology |
| 300 | Business |
| 401 | Science |
| 400 | Business |
| 400 | Engineer |
| 401 | Arts |
| 120 | Maths |
| 134 | Business |

Outcome required

| Major1 | Major2 | Count_of_Students |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Science | Maths | 2 |
| Science | Arts | 2 |
| Science | Business | 2 |
| Maths | Engineer | 2 |
| Engineer | Business | 2 |

I have tried many queries of which the closest (logically) was:

```
SELECT distinct A.Major as Major1, 
       B.Major as Major2, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 where StudentID = B.StudentID and StudentID = A.StudentID) as Count_of_Students 
FROM Table1 A
inner join Table1 B on A.Major <> B.Major 
having Count_of_Students>=2 
order by Count_of_Students desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately MySQL doesn't have PIVOT , which is the first step needed to give the expected result so you have to use:

```
 select StudentID,
        max(case when ColumnSequence=1 then Major end) Major1,
        max(case when ColumnSequence=2 then Major end) Major2
 from (
        Select StudentID, 
               Major,
               row_number() over(partition by StudentID order by StudentID) ColumnSequence
        from tbl ) as t1
 group by StudentID
```

Above query will convert rows to columns , if you have more than two values per StudentID add another  condition max(case when ColumnSequence=2 then Major end) Major3.

Then use below query to find pairs more than once.
*Note*. I added the following values (201,'Science'), (201,'Maths') to get a count more than once.

Use:

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEAST(Major1, Major2), ',', GREATEST(Major1, Major2)) as pair, 
       COUNT(*) as unique_pair_repeats
FROM  ( select StudentID,
               max(case when ColumnSequence=1 then Major end) Major1,
               max(case when ColumnSequence=2 then Major end) Major2
        from ( Select StudentID, 
                      Major,
                      row_number() over(partition by StudentID order by StudentID) ColumnSequence
               from tbl 
             ) as t1
       group by StudentID 
       ) as t2 
GROUP BY pair
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Check the demo for more info: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=acf26229e885e5e9bd02a90f7c7b057f